# What data types in C language are these variables and where I am wrong?

Tags: c, initialization, printf, compile-time-constant, conversion-specifier

Now I am learning the **C language** and I have two tasks. Define variables and print them Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Excersise 1\n\n");
    int cVarOne = -250;
    int cVarTwo = 250;
    int cVarThree = 4589498;
    double cVarFour = 10000000000000000000;
    double cVarFive = -9000000000000000000;
    
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%.0lf\n%.0lf\n\n", cVarOne,cVarTwo,cVarThree,cVarFour,cVarFive);
    
    printf("Excersise Two\n\n");
    unsigned short cVarSix = 43112;
    int cVarSeven = -1357674;
    int cVarEight = 1357674;
    int cVarNine = -1357674000;
    unsigned int cVarTen = 3657895000;

    printf("%u\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%lu\n", cVarSeven, cVarEight, cVarNine, cVarTen);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for exercise 1 the following message appears:

[Excersise 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVbxc.png)

and for exercise two the same numbers that are set as variables are not printed propetly. Here is the result:

[Excersise 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6m6H.png)

I tried to use different types, but without result. Where am I wrong? What data types and specifiers should be used and why do these errors occur?

I am using this online compiler: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of providing links type the relevant information in your question.

Comment: You might want to quote any error messages instead of giving links to screenshots. Some people are too lazy or afraid to follow links.

Comment: `10000000000000000000` is an integer. Try `double cVarFour = 10000000000000000000.0;`

Comment: `cVarSeven` is an integer, but you are printing it with `%u`.  I suspect you forgot to include `cVarSix` in the arguments passed to `printf`.

Comment: If the compiler is not giving you a warning about the mismatch between the number of arguments and the number of format specifiers, you should turn up the diagnostics.

Comment: In the second exampe, `%lu` is expecting `unsigned long` but your variable is `unsigned int`. Arguments for variadic functions are not automatically converted to a larger type as they would be for a defined argument type: they have their own rules about type promotions. At run-time the code will assume that the argument passed to `%lu` was the correct type and size and will fail if it isn't.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as text

Answer (score 2):

The warning in Exercise 2 is self-explanatory, simple use the correct conversion specifier for unsigned int, as taught in chapter 1 of your favourite C book. The rest of this answer is regarding Exercise 1:

---

**Why you get the warning:**

Integer constants, these things: `123`, have a type just like variables.

`10000000000000000000` is not a floating point type since it doesn't end with `.` (`double`) or `.f` (float), but a fixed point signed integer. The compiler will try to find the smallest signed integer type where the value will fit, but it fails to find one at all.

The reason is because 10,000,000,000,000,000,000 = 10^19 is larger than the largest signed 64 bit integer, which can only hold values up to 2^63 - 1 = 9.22*10^18.

The compiler notes however that the value might fit in a 64 bit unsigned integer since 2^64 -1 = 18.44*10^18, large enough. Hence it tries that, but gives you the warning for writing such smelly code.

---

**Solution:**

Use `10000000000000000000.0` which is of type `double`.
Or better yet, use `10e18` which is also `double` but readable by humans.

---

**General best practices:**

- Never mix floating point and fixed point in the same expression.
- Never mix `float` and `double` in the same expression. (Stay clear of `float` entirely on most mainstream systems like PC.)
- When size and portability matters, never use the default integer types of C like `int`, `long` etc. Use the types from `stdint.h` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Each integer type has a fixed size in bytes for internal representations of values. As a result there is a limit for the maximum and a minimum value that can be stored in an integer type.

For example for the type `uintmax_t` the following characteristics can be provided by the compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    uintmax_t x = UINTMAX_MAX;

    printf( "sizeof( uintmax_t ) = %zu and the maximum value is %"
            PRIuMAX "\n", sizeof( x ), x );

}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( uintmax_t ) = 8 and the maximum value is 18446744073709551615
```

When you are using integer constant without suffix like this `10000000000000000000` then the compiler selects the type of the constant the first signed integer type that can represent such a constant. However neither signed integer type including `long long int` can represent this constant. So the compiler issues a message that such a constant can be represented only in an unsigned integer type.

You could use a constant with a suffix like

```
double cVarFour = 10000000000000000000llu;
```

The suffix determines that the constant has the type `unsigned long long int`.

As for the second message then you have to use correct conversion specifiers with arguments.

The conversion specifier `lu` is designed to output values of objects of the type `unsigned long int`. However the corresponding argument of the call of printf

```
printf("%u\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%lu\n", cVarSeven, cVarEight, cVarNine, cVarTen);
```

has the type `unsigned int`

```
unsigned int cVarTen = 3657895000;
```

So either use the conversion specifier `u` like

```
printf("%u\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%u\n", cVarSeven, cVarEight, cVarNine, cVarTen);
```

or cast the argument to the type `unsigned ling` like

```
printf("%u\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%lu\n", cVarSeven, cVarEight, cVarNine, ( unsigned long )cVarTen);
```

Also the length modifier `l` in this format specification `%.0lf` has no effect. You could just write `%.0f`

Comment: `ll` not needed in `double cVarFour = 10000000000000000000llu;`. OK as `10000000000000000000u;`.  An `l` or `ll` are infrequently needed in a _constant_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But it makes the code clear. For example what conversion specifier to use to output this constant?